# IOS - Dismiss keyboard when UIPickerView is touched

Tags: ios, keyboard, hide, uipickerview

I am building a converter app. In the main screen I have a text field to input numbers and below the text field a picker view will allow users to select conversion parameters, (for example kg to g).

I can hide the keyboard when user click the background by using the following method

```
 (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [self.enterInput resignFirstResponder];
```

but when I touch the picker view the keyboard is not hiding.

My question is how to dismiss the keyboard when a user touches the picker view.

Comment: Can't you hide the keyboard when you are showing the PickerView?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9zRYaEUNwXMUF8zRUNhTW1xRWc/edit?pli=1

textfield and picker view are placed in the same screen

Comment: you could think it on another way .. to hide the keyboard when the text field is end editing .. I think this is better for your case.

Comment: Where did you put your touchesBegan:withEvent: code? Is it in a subclass of UIPickerView that you created?

Comment: @Josh I've tried in both super and sub class, but it is not working.

Comment: @user1292441 Hey man. Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got a solution**

1)  First Create a hidden roundRect botton and change the type to custom (fit the size of the picker).

2) Create a touch up inside action

```
 - (IBAction)hiddenButtonToHideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [self.enterInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

3) Create a keyboard appear notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardAppear:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

4) Create a keyboard disappear notification

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

5)  Make the button visible when keyboard is appeared

```
 -(void)onKeyboardAppear:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    hiddenButtonToHideKeyboard.hidden=NO;
}
```

6) Hide the button when the keyboard is disappeared

```
-(void)onKeyboardHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    hiddenButtonToHideKeyboard.hidden=YES;
}
```

5) done

*I dont think it is a perfect solution but it works for me :)*

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my code. I climb the responder chain and reassign the responder. I put this in my method that shows the pickerView. So far no unexpected issues. Seems to work if a keyboard was showing and seems not to crash if there wasn't a keyboard showing.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. UIPickerViews are a fairly complex system of nested UIViews which is why you weren't getting any response from the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. What you can do is create your UIPickerView subclass as follows:

```
//
//  MyPickerView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// Protocol Definition that extends UIPickerViewDelegate and adds a method to indicate a touch
@protocol MyPickerViewDelegate <UIPickerViewDelegate>

// This is the method we'll call when we've received a touch. Our view controller should implement it and hide the keyboard
- (void)pickerViewDidReceiveTouch:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;

@end

@interface MyPickerView : UIPickerView

// We're redefining delegate to require conformity to the MyPickerViewDelegate protocol we just made
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyPickerViewDelegate>delegate;

@end


//
//  MyPickerView.m
//

#import "MyPickerView.h"

@implementation MyPickerView
@synthesize delegate = _myPickerViewDelegate; // We changed the data type of delegate as it was declared in the superclass so it's important to link it to a differently named backing variable

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // We make sure to call the super method so all standard functionality is preserved
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (hitView) {
        // This will be true if the hit was inside of the picker
        [_myPickerViewDelegate pickerViewDidReceiveTouch:self];
    }

    // Return our results, again as part of preserving our superclass functionality
    return hitView;
}

@end
```

Then in your ViewController change it to conform to `<MyPickerViewDelegate>` instead of `<UIPickerViewDelegate>`. This is ok since `MyPickerViewDelegate` inherits from `UIPickerViewDelegate` and will pass through the standard `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods.

Finally implement `pickerViewDidReceiveTouch:` in your view controller:

```
- (void)pickerViewDidReceiveTouch:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    [enterInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: @Clement Glad to help. Hopefully it worked for you. If it did, please be sure mark the answer as correct. Thanks.